# I need to some test cases for Smallest Enclosing Circle

Tags: c, input

I need to some test cases for "Smallest Enclosing Circle Problem" to check accuracy of my code. I need to points(that are as input) and the radius and center point(as output).
Thanks.

""The smallest-circle problem or minimum covering circle problem is a mathematical problem of computing the smallest circle that contains all of a given set of points.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem""

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For example: We have n points(a1,b1)...(an.bn). We know there is a unique the minimal circle that contains all the points. I need the radius and center point of it circle to check accuracy of my code.

Comment: That's still not a question.

Comment: My question: There is a software gives to us the radius and center point of the mentioned circle with inserting the points?

Comment: Two things: 1) Make that clear in the question itself next time so that we understand exactly what you're asking and 2) Asking for a software recommendation is off-topic because it tends to lead to opinionated answers and heated discussion

Comment: sorry. There is a references that i find my asking?  for example, when the points are(3.5,4) (1,2),(1.5,3),(1.22,4).... what is the radius and center point of circle that contains all the points and is also the smallest.

Comment: The center is the mathematical average, its radius is the distance to the furthest point. No mathematical challenge at all.

Comment: .. ah wait, that's the *bounding* circle. Still, the wiki page contains enough pointers to get you started.

Comment: Thanx Jongware. But it is only animation. I need the real value.

Answer (score 1):

yes. I find. We can use  function [center,radius] = minboundcircle(x,y,hullflag) of matlab.